# Изменение цвета при скролле к определенному блоку

Tags: javascript, html, css

В мобильной версии есть фиксированная иконка звонка, она оранжевого цвета, и на сайте есть секции оранжевого цвета, нужно чтоб когда иконка при скролле достигала этих секций меняла цвет, например на белый. Как это реализовать?

Пример https://job.kolesa.kz/ но тут изменения происходят с шапкой сайта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Изменить иконку звонка не пробовали????

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если вы внимательно изучите сайт, который приложили, то увидите что там идёт игра с картинками в каждой секции, а не смена цвета. Имею ввиду смену цвета лого и ссылок, остальное не изучал). Они просто дублируются с нужными цветами. Можно наглядно это наблюдать, если сильно увеличить зум сайта и сделать так чтобы 1 половина текста ссылок попадала на 1 секцию, а 2-ая на вторую и навести мышку, цвет будет меняться только в той секции, где навели мышку

Comment: ого вот это на придумывали, но можно ли реализовать мою идею? без подобного дублирования, может узнать положение секции нужной, и сделать функцию по типу, при достижение этой секции иконка начнет изменяться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Например что-то такое**

```
 const icon = document.querySelector('.icon');
// Элемент иконки
const text = document.querySelector('.text');
// Блок или секция

// Обработчик при скролле
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
// Высота блока или секции
  let stepColor = text.getBoundingClientRect().height;
// Положение на экране 
  let scrollY = window.scrollY;

  if (scrollY > stepColor) {
    icon.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
  }
  if (scrollY > stepColor * 2) {
    icon.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  }
  if (scrollY < stepColor) {
    icon.style.backgroundColor = 'black'
  }

})
```